# How to change "positionFromTop" option based on screen size

Tags: lightbox2

I want the lightbox to be in the middle of the screen on every device.

If i change the number to 300(px) it looks good on mobile but not on pc. And when i change it to 150 it looks good on pc but not on mobile. I tried using CSS classes but it didnt work for me.

Comment: Need to include a snippet with a reproducible example of your code